# How to pass BOOST_ROOT and BOOST_LIBRARY to CMake?

Tags: boost, cmake

I want to install dlib module for python I have installed *CMake* and *boost-python* but when I install dlib It gives me the error:

> We couldn't find the right version of boost python. If you installed boost and you are still getting this error then you might have installed a version of boost that was compiled with a different version of visual studio than the one you are using.  So you have to make sure that the version of visual studio is the same version that was used to compile the copy of boost you are using.
>   --  Set the BOOST_ROOT and BOOST_LIBRARYDIR environment variables before running cmake.

E.g.  Something like this:

```
set BOOST_ROOT=C:\local\boost_1_57_0

set BOOST_LIBRARYDIR=C:\local\boost_1_57_0\stage\lib
```

I can't figure out how to set `BOOST_ROOT` and `BOOST_LIBRARYDIR` paths.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To temporary set environment variables before running CMake you can type those commands in the console:

```
set BOOST_ROOT=C:\local\boost_1_57_0
set BOOST_LIBRARYDIR=C:\local\boost_1_57_0\stage\lib
cmake ...
```

To set them permanently, you might use [setx](https://superuser.com/questions/79612/setting-and-getting-windows-environment-variables-from-the-command-prompt) or click through Windows GUI.

I suggest against those approaches, the more clean and reliable way would be passing those variables to the CMake directly:

```
cmake -DBOOST_ROOT=C:\local\boost_1_57_0 -DBOOST_LIBRARYDIR=C:\local\boost_1_57_0\stage\lib
```

Comment: After setting variables according to your solution when I run "pip install dlib" in command-line that gives me same error i-e "Set the BOOST_ROOT and BOOST_LIBRARYDIR" however boost have successfully installed.

Comment: how do you set these variables in the cmake gui?

Answer (score 0):

Just add them after the `cmake` call with `-D`. In your case that would be

```
cmake -DBOOST_ROOT=C:\local\boost_1_57_0 -DBOOST_LIBRARYDIR=C:\local\boost_1_57_0\stage\lib ..
```

You should clear your CMake cache (delete build directory or just the CMakeCache.txt file) prior to the given command.