Boost Version Bug
can somebody help me with this error
CMake Error at C:/Users/Admin/AppData/Local/Programs/CLion/bin/cmake/win/x64/share/cmake-3.27/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:230 (message):
  Could NOT find Boost (missing: system filesystem thread date_time chrono
  regex serialization program_options) (found suitable version "1.84.0",
  minimum required is "1.55")
Call Stack (most recent call first):

Happens when i try to compile this is my values for cmake:
    BOOST_INCLUDEDIR    C:\local\boost_1_84_0\boost_1_84_0
    BOOST_LIBRARYDIR    C:\local\boost_1_84_0\boost_1_84_0\libs
    BOOST_ROOT          C:\local\boost_1_84_0\boost_1_84_0\boost

I tried reinstalling boost both versions tried using Vkpkg it would not pick those packages up either.

Your boost compiled library files are missing or aren't built with the right compiler or compiler settings

Pass to cmake additional option -DBoost_DEBUG=ON. That way CMake will print which exact names of library files it needs. Compare these names with ones which you actually have.

I tried reinstalling boost both versions tried using Vkpkg it would not pick those packages up either. Is your compiler msvc? Remember you can't use msvc boost for MinGW or vise versa. The compiled binaries will be named differently and match the compiler. With that said you can use vcpkg with MinGW but you need to change the triplet to use one that is for MinGW and not for msvc. The default x64-windows is msvc

@drescherjm
I am using the boost dependancy from the official sourceforge page for boost i didnt get the msvc one i got the regular .zip file i tried the one from boost.org too both had the same issue and im using clion

Did you compile it from the source code with your compiler?

im using clion CLion is not a compiler. It's an IDE that can use several different compilers. What compiler are you using with CLion? You have to use that same compiler when you build boost.

@drescherjm i know i found MSVC but it cant find it do you know how am i able to link it?

It should just work with no special settings if the boost you have installed matches the compiler that you are using. If it doesn't match it won't work. You have not given us enough information to effectively help you. Like your compiler version. And exactly what files you have in the C:\local\boost_1_84_0\boost_1_84_0\libs folder.

@drescherjm i have a custom installation directory thats why it wont locate it

Set BOOST_ROOT to C:\local\boost_1_84_0\boost_1_84_0 from cmake-gui

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38905480/how-to-pass-boost-root-and-boost-library-to-cmake

@drescherjm
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:17 (project):
Generator
Visual Studio 17 2022

could not find any instance of Visual Studio.
i found the tutorial i used for this project and it said to use MSVC earlier and thats why i asked how to link it this is what error i keep getting its no longer a boost issue

Maybe your compiler you were using in CLion is actually MinGW and that was your problem with boost because you can't use msvc boost with MinGW.

@drescherjm MSVC 2022 is selected in the settings
